# Chrome extension making mouse click with extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to make particular elements act as it was clicked on them by calling another function? For example I am trying to make an extension which will automatically clicks a button once I click on the extension. Is it possible to achieve this and if so can somebody point me to the direction of how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be done by the content script. I would add a listener to the extension icon click in the background page. After the callback is triggered, I would inject a content script into the page with UI element. And in this content script I would find a button and trigger click on it.

Comment: I believe yes, that's how I would go about it.

Comment: Ok, I will try just now to do it, I will mark your answer after it, many thanks!