# Global Keyboard and Mouse Listener in Chrome OS

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-app

I'm still learning about developing of Chrome APP. I want to ask if there's a way to monitor or check for keypress and mouseclick event listener outside of the chrome app?

Comment: To clarify, you're talking about ChromeOS apps?

Comment: Implementation of mouse click was answered in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39958812/chrome-extension-making-mouse-click-with-extension). Suggested to use [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). For the [keyboard](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/keyboardevent-keys-codes), you are mainly referring to [**`KeyboardEvent/s`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent), which are used as a parameter passed to **`keydown`**, **`keypress`**, and **`keyup`** event listeners.

Comment: @Xan yes sir, chrome os apps

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 Hi sir, can chrome app api use content scripts method?

Comment: I can answer that one, basically no.

Comment: @Xan is chrome extension api can capture global keypress event?